# Sampler Result setResponseData not setting in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, oracle-coherence

I am writing a custom java class to grab objects from a Coherence grid. It works well through JMeter, but the response data isn't filling it's place in the JMeter GUI. This is how I'm filling the SamplerResult:

```
result.setResponseData(getResponseData(cache.get(key)).getBytes());
```

the `getResponseData(Object);` returns a simple String that I'm pulling the bytes out of. But, the response data is still empty. I can put the data inside of the `result.setSamplerData(String)` but it's it will not populate inside of the ResponseData. It needs to be inside of the ResponseData because it's the only way that a `Regular Expression Extractor` can be used.

Is there something here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setResponseData(String, Encoding)` or `setResponseData(byte[])` is correct when implementing a sampler.

The regular expression extractor uses, depending on what you set in the gui, one of the following:
`getResponseDataAsString(), getResponseMessage(), getResponseCode(), getResponseHeaders(), getUrlAsString()`.

So this should work, if your `byte[]` is something that represents a valid string.

Alternatively, just setting your variables in your sampler might solve your current use case:
`getThreadContext().getVariables().put(name, value);`